# Getting a debug console when running `debugpy` on the command line

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-remote, debugpy

I'm trying to use my external terminal on my local computer to as the console in a debugging session for Python running on a remote machine.  I've successfully attached to a `debugpy` invocation I ran over ssh, but I expected that then in that terminal I would have a console session, but it looks like instead debugpy is just acting as an engine which VSCode attaches to for its regular debug functionality.

I've tried using a "launch" style debug session with "externalTerminal" specified but I don't know how I'd tell VSCode to run in the terminal which isn't even running on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's currently no way to redirect the Python REPL from a remote debugpy session to a local terminal.

If you want to interact with the remote Python process through a console, you can use [Remote-SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) or [Jupyter-notebook](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_connect-to-a-remote-jupyter-server).